# JavaScript Error: "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" on window.open in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

```
$('#intent').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(e.target.href, 'intent', 'width=560,height=520,location=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,startus=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0');
});
```

In Internet Explorer 8, this code throws a JavaScript error: "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients." The code is pretty straightforward. I feel like I've written something almost exactly like this before. I'm not sure why it's throwing an error now.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=iancmyers" id="intent">@iancmyers</a>
```

The IE8 debugging tools say the error is being thrown on window.open.

Comment: what is the `intent` element? can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is researching this issue, I have found that with IE11, this issue happens if the target URL that I pass to window.open() performs a redirect to another URL.

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be conflicts between the anchor tag's default behavior (to navigate to it's `href`) and your click event. Try removing the `href` attribute from the anchor, hard coding it (for now, at least) in your javascript and see if that helps.

Comment: Even when I hard code the URL as the first parameter of window.open I still get the same error.

Comment: @IanChristianMyers can you try changing the anchor tag to a button and remove the `stopPropagation` call in your handler?